# How to default into edit mode instead of insert mode when entering content into a cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I directly start to type content into a cell, Excel is in *Input Mode*, which means I could easily reference cells in formulas. Unfortunately most of the time I do not enter formulas, but simple text - hitting a cursor key here means "leaving the cell", which is most annoying when I try to correct a spelling mistake.

I am aware that I can use `F2` to enter *Edit Mode*, I just happen to realize that when it is too late.

Hence: **How can I make Excel enter *Edit Mode* instead of *Insert Mode* by default?**

More details on [Can I reactivate the cursor keys for modifying a cell reference in a formula?](https://superuser.com/questions/485358/can-i-reactivate-the-cursor-keys-for-modifying-a-cell-reference-in-a-formula)

For the record: I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

Comment: This is so frustrating. I start typing in a cell and press the left key to go back and adjust something. Instead I am now referencing the cell to my left. I don't ever want anything other than F2 mode.

Comment: What I can possibly suggest, if for some reason you have some aversion to the `F2` key, you can assign a shortcut/key binding (either native if it supports it for your Excel version, or through, e.g., AHK), to a different key that is more ergonomical to you.  I'm not a fan of G Sheets, but one thing I did like about it was that the enter key initiates edit mode as well as accepts changes and exits edit mode, the consistency of using the `Enter` key to enter and exit cell editing made for a smoother type-flow for me personally.

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across a way to do this in any version of Excel - the "F2" shortcut key is the closest that you will get.